# Eclipse asking me for user password when executing a pull

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

When I try to make a `pull` in eclipse this login screen with the 'git' user pops up asking me for a password:

[image]

Have no idea what's happening. So, how do I get rid of it? I already have a proper user configured and the `pull` works well in command line, but not in Eclipse.

Comment: Are in _Window > Preferences: General > Network Connections > SSH2_ private SSH keys configured that have passwords?

Comment: In the _Private keys_ field the content is 'id_dsa,id_rsa'.

Comment: Maybe at least one of those keys exists and requires a passphrase (a SSH key can be created with and without a passphrase).